# Deducting 25% from more than one item in loop

Tags: php

I wonder if someone could please help me out a little. I have a loop that loops through the contents of a shopping cart. I wish to apply a 25% discount to additional items purchased. So basically 1st item is full price and every other item is reduced by 25%. I've tried various methods but all i seem to get is the discount apply to all or nothing.

The loop below works perfectly if i remove the `if` statement and its contents thus not wishing to apply a discount. As it currently stands it does not add a discount at all. If i remove the `if` condition and use it's contents then it will apply a 25% discount to all items.

```
for($Loop = 0; $Loop < count($Cart); $Loop++)
{
    $Total += $ShoppingCart[$Loop][Price];

    if($Loop > 1) {
        $Total += $ShoppingCart[$Loop][Price];
    $PercentageAmount = 25;
    $TotalPrice = $TotalPrice * ((100-$PercentageAmount) / 100);    
    }
}
```

**Edited:**

Unfortunately none of the answers, although maybe technically good, do not fix my problem. I have had to result to placing 2 if statements within a loop and then calculating their combined total. Not an ideal solution but works perfectly never the less. Somehow i need the sort it so then the most expensive item is at full price. It would be much easier if i was not tied to using a loop in this fashion and instead could use array functions.

```
$i = 0; 
for($Loop = 0; $Loop < count($Cart); $Loop++)
{
    if($i == 0) {
        $Total += $ShoppingCart[$Loop][Price];
    }                               
    if($i > 0) {
        $TotalMulti += $ShoppingCart[$Loop][Price];
        $TotalMulti = $TotalMulti * .75;    
    }
    $i++;
}
$NewTotal = $Total + $TotalMulti;
```

Comment: umm.. why use `((100-$PercentageAmount) / 100)` when you can use `.75`

Comment: If you're starting your loop at 0, then the 0th item will be full price; so the if statement should check to see if $Loop > 0, rather than 1. As it is, the first two items will be full price, rather than just the first one.

Comment: I've tried my code above with 5+ items in the cart and it has not taken effect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
$prices = array_column($ShoppingCart, 'Price');
array_walk($prices, function(&$price, $i) { if($i) $price *= .75; });
$total = array_sum($prices);
```

How it works:

1. The prices are pulled out in their own array -- I much prefer this because the discount code does not mess with the "normal" prices, which might cause unexpected complications.
2. The array of prices is iterated over, and every element but the first is set to 75% of its value.
3. The total price is just the sum of the discounted prices.

This code depends on `array_column`, which is only available starting with PHP 5.5. For earlier versions you can either grab an implementation from [here](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column) or substitute this:

```
$prices = array_map(function($el) { return $el['Price']; }, $ShoppingCart);
```

If the discount percentage is a variable you will also need this modification:

```
$discount = .25;
array_walk(
    $prices,
    function(&$price, $i) use($discount) { if($i) $price *= (1 - $discount); }
);
```

Comment: The prices are predetermined as the items are from a database

Comment: @TheApptracker: Of course. But you might have some other code that uses the prices to calculate something, and modifying in-place would cause interference. For example, if you have free shipping for orders of $100 or more would that be after discounts or before? I 'm going with "everything is independent by default" as a safety measure.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using php 5.3.3, I'll give your answer a go and let you know.

Comment: This is producing an error regards `array_walk`. the error is `syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')'`

Comment: @TheApptracker: Are you *absolutely* sure you are running PHP 5.3?

Comment: @TheApptracker: No, you 'd have to do a `foreach` solution in that case. But really, 5.3 was released 4 years ago; demand an upgrade from your system administrator.

Comment: Thanks @Jon, I will mark your answer as correct as it is the solution that should be applied in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($Loop = 0; $Loop < count($Cart); $Loop++){

    if($Loop > 0) {
        $Total += ($Cart[$Loop]['Price']*0.75);  
    } else {
        $Total += $Cart[$Loop]['Price'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this would apply the deduction to all items if there were more than one.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
for($Loop = 0; $Loop < count($Cart); $Loop++)
{
    # if not first item then discount price
    if($Loop > 1) {
        $PercentageAmount = 25;
        # grab the price
        $itemPrice = $ShoppingCart[$Loop][Price];
        # what should the user pay? 
        $itemDiscountPrice = $itemPrice * (100.0 - $PercentageAmount) / 100.0
        # add it to total
        $Total += $itemDiscountPrice;
    } else {
        # if first item -> full price
        $Total += $ShoppingCart[$Loop][Price];
    }
}
```